# How to find a match to a partial string and then delete the string from the reference file using awk?

Tags: awk, ksh

I have a problem that I have been trying to solve, but have not been able to figure out how to do it.  I have a reference file that has all of the devices in my inventory by bar code.

Reference file:

```
PTR10001,PRINTER,SN A
PTR10002,PRINTER,SN B
PTR10003,PRINTER,SN C 
MON10001,MONITOR,SN A
MON10002,MONITOR,SN B
MON10003,MONITOR,SN C
CPU10001,COMPUTER,SN A
CPU10002,COMPUTER,SN B
CPU10003,COMPUTER,SN C
```

What I would like to do is make a file where I only have to put the abbreviation of what I need on it.
File 2 would look like this:

```
PTR
CPU
MON
MON
```

The desired output of this would be a file that would tell me what items by barcode that I need to pull off the shelf.
Desired output file:

```
PTR10001
CPU10001
MON10001
MON10002
```

As seen in the output, since I cannot have 2 of the same barcode, I need it to look through the reference file and find the first match.  After the number is copied to the output file, I would like to remove the number from the reference file so that it doesn't repeat the number.

I have tried several iterations of awk, but have not been able get the desired output.
The closest that I have gotten is the following code:

```
awk -F'/' '{ key = substr($1,1,3) } NR==FNR {id[key]=$1; next} key in id { $1=id[key] } { print }' $file1 $file2 > $file3
```

I am writing this in ksh, and would like use awk as I think this would be the best answer to the problem.
Thanks for helping me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First solution:**

From your detailed description, I assume order doesn't matter, as you want to know what to pull off the shelf. So you could do the opposite, first read `file2`, count the items, and then go to the shelf and get them.

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{c[$0]++; next} c[substr($1,1,3)]-->0{print $1}' file2 file1
```

output:

```
PTR10001
MON10001
MON10002
CPU10001
```

---

**Second solution:**

Your `awk` is very close to what you want, but you need a second dimension in your array, and not overwriting the existing ids. We will do it with a pseudo-2-d array (BTW `GNU awk` has real 2-dimensional arrays) where we store the ids like `PTR10001,PTR10002,PTR10003`, we retrieve them with `split` and we remove from shelf also.

```
> cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }

NR==FNR {
    key=substr($1,1,3)
    ids[key] = (ids[key]? ids[key] "," $1: $1) #append new id.
    next
}

$0 in ids {
    split(ids[$0], tmp, ",")
    print(tmp[1])
    ids[$0]=substr(ids[$0],length(tmp[1])+2) #remove from shelf
}
```

Output

```
awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
PTR10001
CPU10001
MON10001
MON10002
```

Here we keep the order of `file2` as this is based on the idea you have tried.

Comment: I used the first solution because I could always reorder the output to fit my needs.  I was not able to get the 2nd solution to ever work correctly.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  iniVal[$0]++
  next
}
{
  counter=substr($0,1,3)
}
counter in iniVal{
  if(++currVal[counter]<=iniVal[counter]){
     print $1
     if(currVal[counter]==iniVal[counter]){ delete iniVal[$0] }
  }
}
' Input_file2  FS="," Input_file1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                           ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                                        ##Checking condition if FNR==NR which is true when Input_file2 is being read.
  iniVal[$0]++                                  ##Creating array iniVal with index of current line with increment of 1 each time it comes here.
  next                                          ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  counter=substr($0,1,3)                        ##Creating counter variable which has 1st 3 characters of Input_file1 here.
}
counter in iniVal{                              ##Checking if counter is present in iniVal then do following.
  if(++currVal[counter]<=iniVal[counter]){      ##Checking if currValarray with index of counter value is lesser than or equal to iniVal then do following.
     print $1                                   ##Printing 1st field of current line here.
     if(currVal[counter]==iniVal[counter]){     ##Checking if currVal value is equal to iniVal with index of counter here.
       delete iniVal[$0]                        ##If above condition is TRUE then deleting iniVal here.
     }
  }
}
' Input_file2  FS="," Input_file1               ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I did try it, and it did work well.  However, I chose the one line awk solution below.